# Box View document stuck in 'status: processing', response 202

Tags: box-view-api

All of a sudden Box.com View API stopped processing my files.

I have files which were processed earlier without any problems, now if I upload them again, when requesting them back I'm getting 202 (and retry-after header of 2 seconds).

Listing the status of document shows the following:

```
{
  type: 'document',
  id: '0583eb1295c24ce19e07ec2eabf3c82f',
  status: 'processing',
  name: 'my_file.pdf',
  created_at: '2014-07-27T15:22:09Z'
}
```

Is this normal behaviour of BoxView API that it doesn't process files for more than 30 minutes or is something wrong in my approach (although everything worked earlier just fine)?

Are there any limits for developer accounts? (Looked here: https://developers.box.com/box-view-faq/ but haven't found anything)

Comment: Hi igor, did you find any solution to this problem?? i am also stuck in the same problem from a long time.. please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All documents are converting normally when I test – this may be a specific issue with your account/document. Please email the team at api@box.com in order to investigate further.